# How to read file (w/ Window Path) using jquery/javascript and then upload to another server or pc

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I would like to have a codes in jQuery and PHP that will...

- Read a file (Windows path-e.g.  "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Sample_CSV.csv") from HTML using jQuery/json

< HTML Codes >
File Name : < input type="file" name="FileToBeUploaded" id="FileToBeUploaded" >

- Upload to another server or PC using jQuery and PHP

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with JavaScript (though it is possible by use of Java (such as a Webstart application)). You will have to use a `<input type="file" name="your-upload-name" />` along with a library such as [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).